# Stopping ListView scroll when onDown

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a gesture listener interfering with a `listView` scroll.  "On Finger Down" action won't stop a `listView` scroll once it started, so I was going to write it into code.

I can't find a method to stop a listView when finger touches the list?

I want to do it here:

```
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {

        // Stop Scroll here!

        return true;
    }
```

Is this possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        return true; // Indicates that this has been handled by you and will not be forwarded further.
    }
    return false;
}
```

});

Then ListView will react to clicks, but will not change scroll position.

Taken from this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611085/disable-scrolling-in-listview)

Comment: Thanks; everywhere I try to put it says I need to remove `@Override`.  Where is this method placed? I am using a `ListFragment`.

Comment: I have just edited my answer. so you can implement it anonymously on your listView instance.

Comment: can't really understand your goal by using nested class in listview class. create new question here so other people might help you. i'll have a look also and help you as much as i can.

Comment: I have a question already worth 200 bounty points.  Here it is; you actually fixed two thirds of the issue, but the biggest thing remains:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971808/gesture-listener-affecting-listview-scroll